# How to create AfterSave event for Word document add-in

Tags: c#, office-addins, word-addins

I am new to this add-in programming. 
My requirement is i would like to add AfterSave event for word document from c#.
I have created Application_DocumentBeforeSave event but i want document After Save event.

can any one help me to solve this..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private void Application_DocumentBeforeSave(Document Doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var application = document.Application; // This is inaccessible while the save file dialog is open, so it will throw exceptions.
                while (application.BackgroundSavingStatus > 0) // Wait until the save operation is complete.
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                break;
            }
            catch {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        // If we get to here, the user either saved the document or canceled the saving process. To distinguish between the two, we check the value of document.Saved.
        Application_DocumentAfterSave(document, !document.Saved);
    }).Start();
}

private void Application_DocumentAfterSave(Document Doc, bool isCanceled) {
    // Handle the after-save event. Note: Remember to check isCanceled.
}
```